# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Amazon S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, redux

I was using react-s3 to do some basic file uploading to amazin s3.

code:

```
export const addMovie = (values, history) => async dispatch => {
    await ReactS3.uploadFile(values.poster, config).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
      }).catch(err => {
        alert(err);
      })
    const res = await axios.post('/admin/movie', values);

    history.push('/admin/movies');
    dispatch({ type: "HANDLE_NEW", payload: res.data })
};
```

but I keep getting this error:

> Failed to load *url*: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Have you added cors headers to s3? 
https://medium.com/@pongsakornsemsuwan/aws-s3-upload-with-react-dropzone-s3-uploader-a76021fe385

Comment: @SaurabhNemade is there's no other way to do it using react-s3? do I have to use the dropzone?

Comment: It is possible to use react-s3. You will need to follow this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors-troubleshooting.html 
Basically you will require cors headers anywhere if you are accessing something which is not in current domain name of website. For e.g, in this case from localhost domain name you are trying to access *.amazonaws.com

Even if you use any other service cors need to enabled on them.

Comment: god it, thank you so much Saurabh! really appreciate it.

Comment: if you don't mind writing it as an answer so I can mark it as aswered!:)

Comment: Sure. Just added with more information of cors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS Headers need to be added given at https://medium.com/@pongsakornsemsuwan/aws-s3-upload-with-react-dropzone-s3-uploader-a76021fe385

You will need to follow this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors-troubleshooting.html

You will require cors headers anywhere if you are accessing something which is not in current domain name of website.

For e.g, in this case from localhost domain name you are trying to access *.amazonaws.com Even if you use any other service cors need to enabled on them.

**More on CORS:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS